# Google Apps Script is changing my Array into a string. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a fairly simple call to my code.gs file for some data that lives in a sheet. I am calling this function from a html file to populate a drop down list. So:

Code.gs

```
function getTheStuffINeed() {

  // Get data from sheet
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("ss_id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  var myStuff = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();

  Logger.log(Array.isArray(myStuff));  // true. 
  Logger.log(myStuff); // [[id1, aVal, aSecondVal], [id2, AnotherVal, anotherSecondVal]] 

  return myStuff ; // An array of arrays
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
  // get data
  var myStuff= <?= getTheStuffINeed() ?>;  

  console.log(Array.isArray(myStuff)); // false
  console.log(myStuff); // id1, aVal, aSecondVal, id2, AnotherVal, anotherSecondVal, etc
</script>
```

When my result hits the html page it is no longer an array of arrays, rather a single string of comma separated values.

Can someone please explain what is happening here, and how to fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), the code you write is not executed directly, the server evaluates the template and returns an [HtmlOutput object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output), that the script can serve to the user.

[Printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) execute code and append new content to the HtmlOutput using **contextual escaping** to avoid accidentally allowing a [cross site scripting (XSS) bug](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security), so the result is a safe String with no markup that can cause unexpected code execution.

**You can:**

- Convert the array to a JSON string using the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method and then parse the String as JSON with the [JSON.parse() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as mentioned by Harold.
- Populating the select  asynchronously:

index.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateStuff)
      .getTheStuffINeed();
});

function populateStuff(stuff) {
  var options = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++){
    options += '<option id="'+stuff[i][0]+'" value="'+ stuff[i][1] + '">' + stuff[i][2] + '</option>';
  }
  $('#select').append(options);
}
</script>
```

- Create and populate the select in the template (**NOT** following the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)).

index.html

```
<select>
  <?
  var myStuff= getTheStuffINeed(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) { ?>
      <option id="<?= myStuff[i][0] ?>" value="<?= myStuff[i][1] ?>"><?= myStuff[i][2] ?></option>
  <? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Brilliant. The async touch is going to work perfect for some other tasks I have also. Thanks for the detailed explaination.

Comment: Happy to help (: For more information about the asynchronous client-side JavaScript API take a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Answer (score 2):

here is a fix
on the client you need to write:

```
var myStuff= JSON.parse(<?= getTheStuffINeed() ?>);
```

on the server:

```
  return JSON.stringify(myStuff) ; // An array of arrays
```